# How to create a Array of ArrayAdapter<String>

Tags: java, android

i want to create a array of ArrayAdapter and array of List, to use in some spinners.

This is my script:

```
    String[] items = new String[]{"Select","A","B", "C", "D"};
    ArrayAdapter<String>[] adaptador;
    List<String>[] List;

.....
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inventario);
        restart_spinner(11);
    }

public void restart_spinner(int sp)
{
List[sp] = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(items2));
adaptador[sp] = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, List[sp]);
spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("p"+sp, "id", getPackageName()));
spinner.setAdapter(adaptador[sp]);
}
```

but i get a java.lang.NullPointerException in this line
List[sp] = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(items2));

How i can do to fix that?

Comment: What is `items2 ` ?

Comment: Where is `List` initialized?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem, I changed my script to:

```
 ArrayAdapter<String>[] adaptador= new ArrayAdapter[50];
 List<String>[] List= new List[50];

.........
```